# Reinstalling OS X – Can I restore my data from a Time Machine backup?

Tags: macos, time-machine, reinstall

I have recently bought a new MacBook and would like to reformat my old MacBook and give it to my girlfriend. I have been regularly backing up my old MacBook using Time Machine. My aim is to start afresh with my new MacBook but still have access to my old data.

Is a Time Machine backup sufficient to do this? Or are there any other steps that I need to take before reinstalling OSX?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Migration Assistant will allow you to move data from your Time Machine backup (or even, your old Mac) to your new Mac.

After you've done that, reinstall OS X on your old Mac. Done.

[image]